# modifying a value in viewstate

Tags: asp.net

Say I have a property like...

```
public object MyObject
{
    get { return (object)ViewState["myobject"]; }
    set { ViewState["myobject"] = value; }
}
```

I modify the object like so...

```
object myObjCopy = MyObject;
myObjCopy.ChangeSomething();
MyObject = myObjCopy;
```

Is this the correct method? It just feels really clunky and I wonder if I'm missing something. Is there some clever paradigm which enables modifying viewstate more intuitively without using temporary copys everywhere in my code.

Answer (score 1):

With the property you have defined, you should not need to do any copying like what you have.  I'm not sure what ChangeSomething() does, but you should be able to call it directly on the property.  I would normally not pull it out as an object... It's been a while since I did pure webforms development, but my ViewState helper properties usually looked more like:

```
public string CurrentUsername
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["Username"] is string)
           return (string)ViewState["Username"];
        return null;
    }
    set { ViewState["Username"] = value; }
}
```

Edit: Thinking about it, I guess the copy is probably there just to remove the potential performance overhead of casting every time you reference the property.  I don't think this is a valid optimization in most cases, but if you feel strongly about it, you could hide it with something like this:

```
private string m_CurrentUsername;
public string CurrentUsername
{
    get
    {
        if (m_CurrentUsername == null && ViewState["Username"] is string)
           m_CurrentUsername = (string)ViewState["Username"];
        return m_CurrentUsername;
    }
    set { ViewState["Username"] = m_CurrentUsername = value; }
}
```

Like I said though - I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: I think you are over-analyzing my question, I'm not bothered about the casting overhead, I was just trying to give a simple example. The issue is that if ChangeSomething() returns an object, I can write MyObject = MyObject.ChangeSomething(); which is fine, but if ChangeSomething() returns void and modifies the instance variable, you can't directly modify the viewstate with MyObject.ChangeSomething() as you could if the property wrapped a normal instance variable. At least thats how it appeared to me when I tried it. I assumed it was something to do with the underlying object being serialised.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is that you shouldn't be modifying viewstate at all.  Your controller should create the models and populate the viewstate only just before returning the view.  If you're writing this code in the view, you've got an even bigger problem.  in general, the view should contain little (if any) code that changes or does things.

*Edit:* Oops, I think I just got ViewData (in asp.net mvc) confused with viewdata.  sorry ... to answer your real question, yes, that is just about the only way :-) it's not really clunky when you are dealing with a "bag" API like the viewstate is.